# PHP addslashes failing when files too large

Tags: php

I have a set of PHP scripts that load files into a database for an auto-updater program to use later.  The program works fine until a file exceeds the 10MB range.  The rough idea of the script is that it pulls files from disk in a specific location, and loads them into the database.  This allows us to store in source control, and update in sets as needed.

Initially, I thought that I was hitting a limit on the database SQL based on my initial searches.  However, after further testing, it seems to be something PHP specific.  I checked the Apache error log, but I did not see any errors for this script or the includes. Once the PHP script reaches the addslashes function, the script seems to stop executing.  (I added echo statements between each script statement.)

I'm hoping that it is something simple that I am missing, but I couldn't find anything related to addslashes failing after several hours of searching online.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '****') or die('Could not connect to the database');
mysql_select_db('****') or die('Could not select database');

function get_filelist($path)
{
        return get_filelist_recursive("/build/".$path);
}
function get_filelist_recursive($path)
{
        $i = 0;
        $list = array();
        if( !is_dir($path) )
                return get_filedetails($path);

        if ($handle = opendir($path))
        {
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
                {
                        if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && $file[0]!='.')
                        {
                                if( is_dir($path.'/'.$file) )
                                {
                                        $list = $list + get_filelist_recursive($path.'/'.$file);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        $list = $list + get_filedetails($path.'/'.$file);
                                }
                        }
                }
                closedir($handle);
                return $list;
        }
}
function get_filedetails($path)
{
        $item = array();
        $details = array();
        $details[0] = filesize($path);
        $details[1] = sha1_file($path);
        $item[$path] = $details;
        return $item;
}

$productset = mysql_query("select * from product where status is null and id=".$_REQUEST['pid']);
$prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($productset);

$folder = "product/".$prow['name'];
$fileset = get_filelist($folder);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fileset))
{
    $fh = fopen($key, 'rb') or die("Cannot open file");
    $data = fread($fh,$val[0]);
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fh);
    $filename = substr( $key, strlen($folder) + 1 );
    $query = "insert into file(name,size,hash,data,manifest_id) values('".$filename."','".$val[0]."','".$val[1]."','".$data."','".$prow['manifest_id']."')";
    $retins = mysql_query($query);
    if( $retins == false )
        echo "BUILD FAILED: $key, $val[0] $val[1].<br>\n";
}

header("Location: /patch/index.php?pid=".$_REQUEST['pid']);
```

Comment: Why are you storing 10MB+ files in a database. :( Better would be to store them as actual files on disk and just keep the *filename* in the database.

Comment: It's not a system that I built or designed, just something I need to keep running.  The database stores multiple versions of over a hundred digital products.  It has been working for over 5 years apparently, and just starting to fail as the product files have gotten bigger.  I'm just trying to find a way to keep it going, without having to sidetrack several weeks redesigning the patch system.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use addslashes, use `mysql_real_escape_string` in this case.  Also, you could likely be hitting a [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/packet-too-large.html) limit by trying to insert such large files.  The default value is 1MB.

If you use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) (which is recommended) you can indicate that the column is binary, and it will send the query in chunks.

Also make sure you aren't hitting any PHP memory limits, or maximum execution time.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting mysqli, another alternative is PDO which allows file streams, too.

Comment: I've also tried mysql_real_escape_string with the same issue.  I've tried adjusting the max_allowed_packet setting with no impact, and I believe that it is failing prior to any packetization.  The script just stops running at the addslashes line (or mysql_real_escape_string line), and only when the file exceeds 10MB.  Otherwise, it works fine.